# Изменение размера дочернего виджета при масштабировании колесом родительского

Tags: qt, pyqt5, pyqt6

у меня есть родительский виджет(QWidget). Я рисую на нем сетку с помощью метода paintEvent. Этот виджет имеет дочерний виджет(QWidget). Дочерний виджет может перемещаться только по ячейкам сетки родительского виджета(эти методы я уже переопределил). Мне необходимо реализовать следующий функционал:

Возможность масштабирования сетки. Т.е при прокрутке колесика мыши количество ячеек, которые умещаются в мой экран, возрастает. Соответственно, когда я прокручиваю колесико в другую сторону, то количество уменьшается. Я реализовал эту функциональность в методе wheelEvent.

Увеличивать размер виджета, который находится в ячейке. Т.е при приближении размер виджета растет пропорционально размеру ячейки. С этим у меня проблемы, т.к размер виджета уменьшается/увеличивается не пропорционально увеличению ячейки.
Я пробовал использовать преобразование координат, но ничего не вышло. Сразу оговорю: я реализовывал весь этот функционал в QGraphicsView. Но эти классы не подходят, т.к невозможно поместить на QGraphicsScene виджет, в который установлено окно стороннего приложения. А моя программа подразумевает перехват сторонних окон и установку этих окон в виджет с дальнейшим добавлением данных виджетов на сетку.  Буду признателен за любую помощь!

"""

```
class MoveWidget(QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super(MoveWidget, self).__init__()
    self.click_rect = self.rect()
    self.selected_edge = None
    self.click_pos = None
    self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    self.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow; "
                       "color: red;"
                       "border: 2px solid blue;")
    grid = QGridLayout(self)
    self.setLayout(grid)
    grid.addWidget(QPushButton("fdfdsfdsfdsf"), 0, 0)
    grid.addWidget(QPushButton("1111111111111"), 1, 0)
    self.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 300)

def paintEvent(self, a0) -> None:

    opt = QStyleOption()

    opt.initFrom(self)
    painter = QPainter(self)
    self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PrimitiveElement.PE_Widget, opt, painter, self)


def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.click_pos = event.pos()
    rect = self.rect()
    top = abs(rect.top())
    bottom = abs(rect.bottom())
    left = abs(rect.left())
    right = abs(rect.right())

    if abs(left - abs(self.click_pos.x())) < 30 and (
            abs(bottom - abs(self.click_pos.y())) > 30) and (abs(top - abs(self.click_pos.y())) > 30):
        self.selected_edge = 'left'

    elif abs(right - abs(self.click_pos.x())) < 30 and (
            abs(bottom - abs(self.click_pos.y())) > 30) and (abs(top - abs(self.click_pos.y())) > 30):
        self.selected_edge = 'right'

    elif abs(top - abs(self.click_pos.y())) < 30 and (abs(right - abs(self.click_pos.x())) > 30) and (
            abs(left - abs(self.click_pos.x())) > 30):
        self.selected_edge = 'top'

    elif abs(bottom - abs(self.click_pos.y())) < 30 and (
            abs(right - abs(self.click_pos.x())) > 30) and (abs(left - abs(self.click_pos.x())) > 30):
        self.selected_edge = 'bottom'

    elif (abs(bottom - abs(self.click_pos.y())) < 30) and (abs(right - abs(self.click_pos.x())) < 30):
        self.selected_edge = 'diag_bottom_right'

    elif (abs(bottom - abs(self.click_pos.y())) < 30) and (abs(left - abs(self.click_pos.x())) < 30):
        self.selected_edge = 'diag_bottom_left'

    elif (abs(top - abs(self.click_pos.y())) < 30) and (abs(right - abs(self.click_pos.x())) < 30):
        self.selected_edge = 'diag_top_right'

    elif (abs(top - abs(self.click_pos.y())) < 30) and (abs(left - abs(self.click_pos.x())) < 30):
        self.selected_edge = 'diag_top_left'

    else:
        self.selected_edge = None
    self.click_pos = event.pos()
    self.click_rect = rect
    self.cl = self.mapFromParent(QPoint(rect.x(), rect.y()))
    super().mousePressEvent(event)

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    pos = event.pos()

    x_diff = (round((pos.x() - self.click_pos.x()) / 300) * 300)
    y_diff = (round((pos.y() - self.click_pos.y()) / 300) * 300)

    # Start with the rectangle as it was when clicked.
    rect = QRectF(self.click_rect)

    # c = self.rect().getCoords()
    # rect = QRectF(c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3],)
    self.pos()

    if self.selected_edge is None:

        self.move(self.mapToParent(QPoint(x_diff, y_diff)))
        print(self.pos())
        return
    elif self.selected_edge == 'top':
        rect.adjust(0, y_diff, 0, 0)


    elif self.selected_edge == 'left':

        rect.adjust(x_diff, 0, 0, 0)

    elif self.selected_edge == 'bottom':

        rect.adjust(0, 0, 0, y_diff)

    elif self.selected_edge == 'right':

        rect.adjust(0, 0, (x_diff), 0)

    elif self.selected_edge == 'diag_bottom_right':

        rect.adjust(0, 0, (x_diff), (x_diff))

    elif self.selected_edge == 'diag_top_right':

        rect.adjust(0, -(x_diff), (x_diff), 0)

    elif self.selected_edge == 'diag_bottom_left':

        rect.adjust((x_diff), 0, 0, -(x_diff))

    elif self.selected_edge == 'diag_top_left':

        rect.adjust((x_diff), (x_diff), 0, 0)

    s = self.mapToParent(QPoint(int(rect.x()), int(rect.y())))

    d = rect.getCoords()
    ee = self.mapToParent(QPoint(int(d[2]), int(d[3])))
    self.setGeometry(s.x(), s.y(), int(d[2]), int(d[3]))
    s = self.rect()

    print(self.pos())



  
class WidMain(QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setStyleSheet("background: transparent;")
    self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    self.movewid = MoveWidget()
    self.movewid.setParent(self)
  
    self.factor = 1.0


def wheelEvent(self, event):
    self.factor *= 1.01 ** (event.angleDelta().y() / 15.0)
    self.update()
    print("масштаб", self.factor)
    child = self.children()
    print(child[0].rect(), "геометрия дочернего виджета без применения преобразования в своих координатах")

    transform = QTransform()
    transform.scale(self.factor, self.factor)


    print(transform.mapRect(child[0].rect()), "геометрия дочернего виджета с применения преобразования в своих координатах")
    child[0].setGeometry(transform.mapRect(child[0].rect()))
    print(child[0].rect(),'Новая геометрия дочернего виджета после преобразований')
    transform.reset()
   

def paintEvent(self, a0) -> None:
    opt = QStyleOption()
    opt.initFrom(self)
    painter = QPainter(self)
    self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PrimitiveElement.PE_Widget, opt, painter, self)

    pen = QPen(QColor("blue"))
    pen.setWidth(5)
    painter.setPen(pen)
    child = self.children()
   
    transform = QTransform()
    transform.scale(self.factor, self.factor)
    painter.setTransform(transform)


    for i in range(0, int(self.width()*1000), 300):
        painter.drawLine(i, 0, i, int(self.height()*1000))
    for i in range(0, int(self.height()*1000), 300):
        painter.drawLine(0, i, int(self.width()*1000), i)

    super().paintEvent(a0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication([])

w = WidMain()

w.show()

app.exec()
```

"""